# Reading Excel with edit on read in DataFusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am reading an excel file with google DataFusion Wrangler plugin.  In the excel the first row needs to be discarded, as headers and data start from second row.
Problem is when Wrangler reads and parse-as-excel a file, it gives default option of choosing the first row as header. 
Need some help to isolate such that first row is skipped and header is 2nd row with the data following.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think its possible inside the DataFusion Wlangler plugin. I think you have to remove it before parsing or do it manually afterwards. Why do you need such feature?

Comment: @vitooh basically need to automate entire pipeline, so want to avoid a manual interventions.  Generated excel is automated as well and pushed to cloud storage bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is currently not supported by the Wrangler plugin. As you are already aware, Wrangler will only take a look at the first column to decode headers.

In this case, pre-processing the file to remove the first row is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to filter any column that will always have values (not empty). But you will have to enter the column names by hand after.

Inside the wrangler, go to the column "A", click on the arrow to open the menu.
Then you choose "Filter", and you choose to "Remove rows" if value is empty.
It will remove the first row.

You repeat the operation, but filter to remove if column "A" is equal the value that is the header for the A column.